# Cant reload my React-native app on physical android device

Tags: android, react-native

I want to reload my react native project on my physical anroid device, I have tried the following stuff but nothing is working 
There's no MENU button in my phone
-Shaking the app
-adb shell input keyevent 82
-adb shell input text "RR"

nothing happens when I type these commands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to double tap on your phone screen, This reloads the app too.
Plus do look at this documentation, It provides all the information about how you can settle your physical device. 
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device#running-your-app-on-android-devices